# How can I make a list of line functions into one drawPolygon function with JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, graphics2d

Is there any way I can put this into a simple draw/fillPolygon? I'm trying to draw something which would be much easier and much less redundant with the use of a polygon function but I'm not sure how to use it with `JPanel`.

```
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 4, 3,4));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(3, 4, 5,3));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(5, 3, 12,3));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(12, 3, 11,2));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(11, 2, 9,1));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(9, 1, 3,1));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(3, 1, 0,2));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(0,2,0,3));
g2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 3, 0,4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html).

```
Path2D.Double path = Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(0, 4);
path.lineTo(3, 4);
path.lineTo(5, 3);
path.lineTo(12, 3);
path.lineTo(11, 2);
path.lineTo(9, 1);
path.lineTo(3, 1);
path.lineTo(0, 2);
path.lineTo(0, 3);
path.lineTo(0, 4);
g2D.draw(path);
```

Or use [`drawPolyline(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolyline-int:A-int:A-int-).

```
g2D.drawPolyline(new int[] { 0, 3, 5, 12, 11, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0 },
                 new int[] { 4, 4, 3,  3,  2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                 10);
```

Or use [`drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-) where you don't have to repeat the first point at the end.

```
g2D.drawPolygon(new int[] { 0, 3, 5, 12, 11, 9, 3, 0, 0 },
                new int[] { 4, 4, 3,  3,  2, 1, 1, 2, 3 },
                9);
```

Or create a [`Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) and use it, again without repeating the first point:

```
Polygon polygon = Polygon(new int[] { 0, 3, 5, 12, 11, 9, 3, 0, 0 },
                          new int[] { 4, 4, 3,  3,  2, 1, 1, 2, 3 },
                          9);
g2D.drawPolygon(polygon);
```